Error: cy.task(db:seed) 'task' not registered - during Cypress tutorial on Google Auth
I'm working my way through Google Authentication instructions found here:
https://docs.cypress.io/guides/end-to-end-testing/google-authentication
When I attempt to run the Test Login code I get the following error

cy.task('db:seed') failed with the following error:
The 'task' event has not been registered in the setupNodeEvents method.
You must register it before using cy.task()

I don't see any references to setupNodeEvents cy.task() or db:seed elsewhere on the page.
I tried

commenting out the line - different long-winded error
add a dummy on(task...) block in cypress/cypress.config.js - no change
add setupNodeEvents in cypress.config.ts - syntax error
tried creating the file as .ts and .js

Here's the code block from the page:
describe('Google', function () {
  beforeEach(function () {
    cy.task('db:seed')
    cy.loginByGoogleApi()
  })

  it('shows onboarding', function () {
    cy.contains('Get Started').should('be.visible')
  })
})


See the Try it out green box, there is a link to real-world-app which demos the code you are trying out.

the spec for google auth
the code for task db:seed

I don't think the db:seed is specifically needed for auth login, it is just posting the seed command to the server.
All the specs should be working, but you need a google client credentials set up in .env to run the google spec.
# Google Auth Configuration to be added to .env when running "yarn dev:google"
# client ID should look something like <identifier>.apps.googleusercontent.com
# VITE_GOOGLE_CLIENTID="your-client-id"
# VITE_GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET="your-client-secret"
# GOOGLE_REFRESH_TOKEN="your-refresh-token"

